# using geojson data with AngularJS expandable ui-grid

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, geojson, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid from Angular JS to display some json (specifically geojson) information. I am using an expandable grid to list extra metadata. The json I am using is setup like so:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"totalFeatures": 36,
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "someid",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    [-71.62599996, 41.250999959999994],
                    [-71.49899628, 41.250999959999994],
                    [-71.49899628, 41.12399619],
                    [-71.62599996, 41.12399619],
                    [-71.62599996, 41.250999959999994]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    },
    "geometry_name": "the_geom",
    "properties": {
        "QUAD_NAME": "Block Island",
        "STATE": "RI",
        "ACQYEAR": "2010",
        "RESOLUTION": "1 Meter",
        "FILMTYPE": "Color",
        "TILE": "sometile",
        "X1": -71.626,
        "Y1": 41.124,
        "X2": -71.499,
        "Y2": 41.251
    }
}
```

I want to show in the subgrid the properties object above.

The ui-grid [expandable grid example](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/306_expandable_grid) uses [this json](https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json) which is an array of keypair objects while mine is just a javascript object with sub properties. Being a new javascript coder, I do not understand how I can tell ui-grid to instead just look into the properties object for the definition I give it.

Below is the relevant code:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        expandableRowTemplate: 'app/map/expandableRowTemplate.html',
        expandableRowHeight: 150,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        selectionRowHeaderWidth: 35,
        expandableRowScope: {
            subGridVariable: 'subGridScopeVariable'
        }
    };

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
        name: 'id',
    }];

    $scope.gridOptions.multiSelect = true;

    $http.get('/assets/rhode.json')
        .success(function(data) {
            //var items = data.features;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
                data.features[i].subGridOptions = {
                    columnDefs: [{
                        name: 'QUAD_NAME',
                        //        field: 'QUAD_NAME'
                    }, {
                        field: 'ACQYEAR',
                        //       field: 'ACQYEAR'
                    }],
                    data: data.features[i].properties
                }
            }

            $scope.gridOptions.data = data.features;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the grid to display nested properties of your object, you need to add a function to your object and then in the field parameter, call this function.

For example, assuming that your object name is data you would do

```
data.getQuadName = function(){
    return this.features.properties.QUAD_NAME;
}
```

and then in your subGridOptions you would do

```
{
   name:'QUAD_NAME,
   field: 'getQuadName()'
 }
```

Let me know if you want me to be more verbose in my answer, but I think it's pretty straight forward :)